# error: writable atomic property cannot pair a synthesized setter/getter with a user defined setter/getter

Tags: objective-c, xcode, compiler-construction, properties

I recently tried to compile an older Xcode project (which used to compile just fine), and now I'm seeing a lot of errors of this form:

> `error: writable atomic property 'someProperty' cannot pair a synthesized setter/getter with a user defined setter/getter`

The code pattern which causes these errors always looks like this:

```
// Interface:

@property (retain) NSObject * someProperty;

// Implementation:

@synthesize someProperty; // to provide the getter
- (void)setSomeProperty:(NSObject *)newValue
{
    //..
}
```

I can see why the error is being generated. I tell the compiler to synthesize my property accessors (both getter and setter), and then immediately afterward I override the setter manually. That code has always smelled a little off.

So, what is the proper way to do this? If I use `@dynamic` instead of `@synthesize`, I will have to write the getter as well. Is that the only way?

Comment: Does this only happen with `atomic` properties? In case of atomic properties it might be a good idea to keep the getter/setter pair in sync in respect to locking strategy. This is difficult if one part is synthesized while the other is custom code.

Comment: It certainly does go away if I make the property nonatomic. Interesting. I hadn't even thought about the synchronization issue.

Comment: I visited this topic to find a solution to that exact problem. I don't really want to write a getter and a setter by myself. Oh well…

Comment: By default every property is atomic and we need to make them nonatomic explicitly. Atomic properties are thread safe, so we can't implement setter and getter for them because it will change it's thread safe functionality. I hope you get the reason why you are getting this error.

Answer (score 224, accepted):

I had the same problem and after doing a bit of research, here is my conclusion about this issue:

The compiler warns you about a `@property` that you declared as atomic (i.e. by omitting the `nonatomic` keyword), yet you provide an incomplete implementation of how to synchronize access to that property.

To make that warning disappear:

If you declare a `@property` to be atomic then do one of the following:

- use `@dynamic` or;
- use `@synthesize` and keep the synthesized setter and getter or;
- provide a manual implementation of *both* the setter and the getter (without using one of the above directives).

If you declare the `@property` with `(nonatomic)` then you can mix manual and synthesized implementations of getters and setters.

**Update: A Note on Property Auto-Synthesis**

As of LLVM 4.0, CLang provides auto-synthesis for declared properties that are not `@dynamic`. By default, even if you leave out the `@synthesize`, the compiler will provide getter and setter methods for you. However, the rule for atomic properties is still the same: Either let the compiler provide *both* the getter and the setter, OR implement them *both* yourself!

Answer (score 14):

You need to implement the getter also. Example:

```
// Interface:

@property (retain) NSObject * someProperty;

// Implementation:

- (void)setSomeProperty:(NSObject *)newValue
{
    @synchronized (self)
    {
        // ...
    }
}

- (NSObject *)someProperty
{
    NSObject *ret = nil;

    @synchronized (self)
    {
        ret = [[someProperty retain] autorelease];
    }

    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 12):

This question, among the other top hits you get from searching for "objective C custom property", are not updated with information about "setter =" or "getter =".

So, to supply more information on this question:

You can supply the @property call with your own method by writing

```
    @property(setter = MySetterMethod:, getter = MyGetterMethod)
```

Notice the colon for the supplied setter method.

Reference [Apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Chapters/ocProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH17-SW1)

*EDIT:
I'm not quite sure how the new changes to Objective-C's properties (they are much more intelligent now) change the answers to this question. Perhaps it should all be marked as out of date.*

Comment: I found that setting the setter method didn't actually remove the warning. e.g. -> "@property (assign, setter = setDelegate:) id delegate;" In this instance all I can do is add my own getter or add the nonatomic property, which I'm not sure if I should, given that I'm setting the delegate myself 'atomically', it doesn't matter having the nonatomic property, or so I understand.

Comment: Interesting, David. What "version" of Objective-C is this in (I suppose saying the XCode-version would be more helpful)?

I'm not sure what the recent changes to Objective-C, specifically with iOS 6 affect this.

Answer (score 0):

For others who are getting this error not for the reason OP described, you likely have the same issue as me:

You have a @property with the same name as a -()method.

Something like this:

```
@property UIView *mainView;

-(UIView *)mainView;
```