# What does this mean? "Writable atomic property 'fileManager' cannot pair a synthesized setter/getter with a user defined setter/getter"

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, xcode4

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [error: writable atomic property cannot pair a synthesized setter/getter with a user defined setter/getter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3227176/error-writable-atomic-property-cannot-pair-a-synthesized-setter-getter-with-a-u)

I have a header file where I declare an atomic property, like this:

```
@property (retain) FileManager *fileManager;
```

Then I synthesize that in the implementation file:

```
@synthesize fileManager;
```

And then I write my own accessor for lazy initialization:

```
- (FileManager*)fileManager {
    if (fileManager) {
        return fileManager;
    }

    FileManager *fm = [[FileManager alloc] init];
    self.fileManager = fm;
    [fm release];

    return fileManager;
}
```

Everything works perfectly and Xcode 3.2 never complained. But Xcode 4 warns:

> Writable atomic property 'fileManager' cannot pair a synthesized
>   setter/getter with a user defined setter/getter

When I get that right it is trying to say: "You cannot overwrite synthesized getters/setters like you did the past 3 years, even though it worked perfectly!"

Obviously surpressing warnings is stupid. This property really needs to be thread-safe, and I really want this lazy initialization. What am I supposed to do now?

**Edit:** According to [this question and answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3227176/error-writable-atomic-property-cannot-pair-a-synthesized-setter-getter-with-a-u), the `@synchronize` code is missing here. **How would I make this accessor properly thread-safe by hand?**

I tried rewriting it to this:

```
- (FileManager*)fileManager {
    @synchronized(self) {
        if (fileManager) {
            return fileManager;
        }

        FileManager *fm = [[FileManager alloc] init];
        self.fileManager = fm;
        [fm release];


        return fileManager;
    }
}
```

But the warning doesn't go away. So when I get the answer of  that other question right, the only way to get rid of this warning is to either not customize synthesized atomic property accessors or to omit the @synthesize completely and do it all by hand: The accessor AND the mutator. Of course, this would suck. Is there a better solution to the problem?

What does it mean if I set it to `@dynamic fileManager` instead of `@synthesize fileManager`?

**Edit:** So I tried using `@dynamic` instead of `@synthesize`. It really means to implement both accessor and mutator manually. Then why would I even want to declare it as `@dynamic` at all?

Comment: 'Harvard Voodoo' says atomicity != thread safety

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you declare an @property that is atomic -- the default -- you must either use @dynamic, let the compiler @synthesize everything or provide an implementation of both the setter and getter.

Comment: Yes it looks like you're right. But honestly: I hope you're not :-)

Comment: He is. It's the new LLVM compilers that do not like this.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the pattern for lazy initialization illustrated in many of the Apple code examples in past years. There is typically a corresponding local variable, by convention with a leading underscore (`_`). In the @synthesize statement you assign it to the ivar:

```
@synthesize fileManager = _fileManager;
```

and you lazily create the local variable.

```
-(FileManager) fileManager {
   if (_fileManager != nil) return _fileManager;
   // etc...
}
```

Comment: Nice, but how does that solve my problem described above? I am already using lazy initialization, and in this example it's not even thread-safe, isn't it? Or is this some advanced Harvard Voodoo I don't get? ;-)

Comment: You are still getting the warnings?