# Is there a way to do lazy initialization of a atomic property without having to write setter and getter by hand?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, xcode4

Apparently it's not possible to use @synthesize when overwriting an atomic property accessor. [Xcode 4 will produce a warning.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7784105/what-does-this-mean-writable-atomic-property-filemanager-cannot-pair-a-synth)

Now, is there another way of using lazy initialization *of atomic properties* while still letting Xcode synthesize both getter and setter automatically, without overwriting any of them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you need to do is write both the setter and the getter. You can still `@synthesize` to get the storage. e.g.:

```
//.h
@property (strong) id x;

//.m

@synthesize x = _x;
- (id)x
{
    @synchronized(self)
    {
        if (!_x)
        {
            _x = [[MyX alloc] init];
        }
        return _x;
    }
}

- (void)setX:(id)x
{
    @synchronized(self)
    {
        _x = x;
    }
}
```

You may need to do additional memory management without ARC and may want to create a different lock (instead of `self`) or use a different synchronisation method, but it'll give you the gist.

Comment: Why is it advised to create a different lock instead of self? What's the point?

Comment: If you have x and y both locking on self you can't access them both at the same time. You probably don't need to have a different lock in a lot of cases, but if you are sharing and object between many threads and have many properties then it may be a performance improvement. Only do it if you've done some testing and are not happy with performance and the testing is highlighting it as a bottleneck...