# Proper way to perform additional code when setting properties

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, properties, nsview

This might seem like a basic question but I'm still getting a handle on properties so please bear with me.

I have a custom NSView subclass that does its own drawing. I've set up support for different styles with a `@property` for setters and a `typedef enum` for human-readable integers. It works great, but the view won't redraw after setting its style unless I manually call `setNeedsDisplay:YES` on the control or resize its parent window.

Logically one would think the solution would be to simply do a `[self setNeedsDisplay:YES]` in the classes' `setStyle:` method, but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to properly do it. Whenever I try to override `setStyle:` it just complains, "Writable atomic property 'style' cannot pair a synthesized getter with a user defined setter".

What should be done in this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, you would just declare your actual ivar/storage as a private property, then manually implement the setter `setStyle:`. In the implementation of `setStyle:`, set your private property/state, and perform your updates. So you just abstract the data from the client's interface. There are other ways to approach this, such as directly setting the ivar.

So an implementation may take the form:

**MONThing.h**

```
@interface MONThing : NSObject

- (void)setStyle:(t_style)pStyle; // << the client's interface

@end
```

**MONThing.m**

```
@interface MONThing ()

@property (nonatomic, assign, readwrite) t_style userStyle; // << the actual storage

@end

@implementation MONThing

- (void)setStyle:(t_style)pStyle
{
    // validate parameter
    // set our data
    self.userStyle = pStyle;
    // perform effects
    [self setNeedsDisplay:true];
}
```

Over time, you will learn multiple ways to accomplish this, and when you would favor one over the other.

Answer (score 1):

If you a setting your own setter then do not use @synthesize and @property. These are for automatic creation of the setter and getter methods. Declaring the variable in the interface file is enough.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3227176/error-writable-atomic-property-cannot-pair-a-synthesized-setter-getter-with-a-u) question. To copy over the answer from the other question:

If you declare a @property to be atomic then do one of the following:

use @dynamic or;
use @synthesize and keep the synthesized setter and getter or;
provide a manual implementation of both the setter and the getter (without using one of the above directives).