# Why can't I customize the getter and setter if class property is atomic?

Tags: objective-c, properties

Why can't I customize the getter and setter of my implementation in iOS if class property is atomic?

```
@property (atomic, strong) NSArray* myArray;
```

Comment: I'm guessing that the synthesised getters and setters handle atomicity for you, which can not be guaranteed if you override them.

Comment: Who says you can't customize the property? What issue are you having?

Comment: possible duplicate of [error: writable atomic property cannot pair a synthesized setter/getter with a user defined setter/getter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3227176/error-writable-atomic-property-cannot-pair-a-synthesized-setter-getter-with-a-u)

Comment: @Rob I know that, thanks. I was asking the OP since they provided no details about the actual issue they are having.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, you can implement your own custom getter and setter for atomic properties. What the compiler will not let you do, though, is to only implement custom rendition one of those two accessor methods and not the other, thereby expecting the compiler to synthesize it for you. And this makes sense: The entire idea of atomic properties is that one cannot access the property at the same time it's being updated. So the compiler can't synthesize one of those atomic accessor methods without synthesizing the other, too, because it has no way to coordinate the atomic nature of its accessor method with yours.

Needless to say, if you do implement your own pair of accessor methods for an `atomic` property, recognize that you are responsible for ensuring the implementation of the atomic behavior.

---

I must confess, though, that I worry when I see discussion of `atomic` in conjunction with something like a `NSArray`. I just want to make sure you are not operating under the assumption that the use of the `atomic` keyword would ensure thread-safety. As general rule, when dealing with an object like an array, you need to wrap all interaction with the object in question within some synchronization mechanism in order to achieve thread-safety, not just the retrieval of the `NSArray` pointer. Thus, this synchronization mechanism is generally implemented a level higher than the basic accessor methods.

Comment: FYI - The reason I asked for clarification (in my 1st comment below the question) was to confirm whether the question should be closed as a duplicate (the one Josh linked). If the first half of your answer actually applies then the question is a duplicate and should be closed.

Comment: IMHO, this question is more "why" and that other question was "what do I do", but can see why you might be inclined characterize it as a dupe, subject to Sandy's clarification. Personally, I think it's quite likely that the correct answer here is not "implement both accessor methods" (as suggested by those other answers), but rather "atomic may not be the right synchronization mechanism" or "perhaps custom accessor is not the right pattern." We'll see.